# How to use sub-query result twice in the query?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have this query:

```
UPDATE QandA SET accepted = IF ( id <> :answer_id, 0, 1 )
  WHERE col1 = ( SELECT related FROM QandA WHERE id = :answer_id ) AND
        col2 = ( SELECT related FROM QandA WHERE id = :answer_id )
```

As you see there is two identical sub-queries. How can I write that sub-query once and use its result twice?

Comment: You can use temp table for storing the sub queries value and use data from temp table in query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use can use `CROSS JOIN`:

```
UPDATE QandA CROSS JOIN
       ( SELECT related FROM QandA WHERE id = :answer_id ) x
    SET accepted = ( id = :answer_id)
WHERE col1 =  x.related AND col2 = x.related;
```

Note that I also removed the `if()`.  This is unnecessary in MySQL where boolean expressions are treated as integers in a numeric context.

An alternative would use `IN`:

```
WHERE ( SELECT related FROM QandA WHERE id = :answer_id ) IN (col1, col2)
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for two sub-queries here, one is enough, just make sure col1 = col2 and you're done:

```
UPDATE QandA SET accepted = IF ( id <> :answer_id, 0, 1 )
  WHERE col1 = ( SELECT related FROM QandA WHERE id = :answer_id ) AND
        col2 = col1
```

Comment: I'm not sure it works, but if it is, then well played. +1